# Postgres copy query connection lost error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, psql

I'm trying to bulk load around 200M lines (3.5GB) of data to an Amazon RDS postgresql DB using the following command:

```
cat data.csv | psql -h<host>.rds.amazonaws.com -U<user> <db> -c "COPY table FROM STDIN  DELIMITER AS ','"
```

After a couple of minutes I get this error:

```
connection not open
connection to server was lost
```

If I run `head -n 100000000 data.csv` to send the first 100M lines instead of all 200M then the command succeeds instead. I'm guessing that there's a timeout somewhere that's causing the query with the full dataset to fail. I've not been able to find any timeout settings or parameters though.

How can I make the bulk insert succeed with the full dataset?

Comment: Tried any of these methods? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602976/bulk-loading-into-postgresql-from-a-remote-client

Comment: That's almost exactly what I am doing, and it's timing out for the full dataset

Comment: It's similar, but not precisely the same. As I read the statement you're using, it basically creates a giant string, then connects to SQL and then it tries to feed the entire string as argument. If you load psql and run something like `\copy ... from '/path/to/data.csv' ...`, I'd imagine the connection might stay alive while the file's content is streamed chunk by chunk. Not committing this as answer, since it's a wild guess, but that would be my hunch as to why 10M lines works (= argument pushed entirely before the connection times out) but not the entire file (= argument still uploading).

Comment: Oh I overlooked that. You're absolutely right. Docs here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY. That did solve the problem! Want to write it up as an answer and get the points?

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I read the statement you're using, it basically creates a giant string, then connects to SQL and then it tries to feed the entire string as argument.

If you load psql and run something like `\copy ... from '/path/to/data.csv'` ..., I'd imagine the connection might stay alive while the file's content is streamed chunk by chunk.

That would be my hunch as to why 10M lines works (= argument pushed entirely before the connection times out) but not the entire file (= argument still uploading).

Comment: Yeah, using the \copy psql command instead of the COPY statement fixed the timeout issue. Thanks!